# When setting critical regions in a two sided hypothesis test, why do we assign equal probabilities to both tails

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, p-value, inference

Consider the problem at https://www.investopedia.com/terms/t/two-tailed-test.asp which states:
"A sample of 100 clients of ABC is taken, and brokerage charges are calculated with the new rates of XYZ broker. If the mean of the sample is \$18.75 and the sample standard deviation is \$6, can any inference be made about the difference in the average brokerage bill between ABC and XYZ broker?"

Here, $H_0: \mu=0 $, and $H_1: \mu =/=0$. A possible test statistic is the sample average (which we'll denote using Z), which approximately follows a normal distribution.
Now, it is said that if the level of significance is 0.05, then the critical values are set at $Z_{0.025}$ and $-Z_{0.025}$. I see why this is a possible choice of critical values.

**But, why choose these critical values over say,** $Z_{0.03}$ and $-Z_{0.02}$? With these new critical values, the probability of lying in the "rejection" region will still be 0.05. The key difference is that the critical values are not direct reflections of each other across the mean of the normal distribution (so there's asymmetry here), but why should this be an issue?

Comment: Cross-post: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3841032/321264.

Comment: For a confidence interval is is usual, but not mandatory, to put half of the 'error probability' in each tail. For test of normal data $H_0: \mu=0$ vs. $H_a: \mu \ne 0,$ it is usually assumed that negative and positive differences are of equal importance.